# How to disable changing the Hamburger Icon to back arrow when Drawer is opened?

Tags: android, xamarin, navigation-drawer, hamburger-menu

I need to show only hamburger icon to user no matter drawerMenu is visible or not. I think I should mention that page is with drawer is not my root page.

That is code of my activity:

```
 public class MainActivity : MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity<MainViewModel>
    {
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            SetSupportActionBar(FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar));
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            SupportActionBar.Title = "All Requests";

            _drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawerLayout);
            _drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                _drawerLayout,
                Resource.String.OpenDrawerString,
                Resource.String.CloseDrawerString);

            _drawerLayout.AddDrawerListener(_drawerToggle);
            _drawerToggle.SyncState();
        }
```

And this is the toolbar view, that I include:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
  android:background="@color/blue"
  android:elevation="4dp"
  style="@style/Base_ToolbarStyle"
  />
```

Comment: try to remove the **_drawerToggle.SyncState()**

Comment: @Thecarisma, unfortunately it does not work. Than I can see only arrow. However I should mention that page is with drawer is not my root page.